# Reactivate window after it's been deactivated c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am building a screen capture application to try and record screen shots of mouse clicks on another (third party) application. I am writing a C# WPF application with a transparent background which can be "clicked through" (so the user can still perform tasks on the other application) with a "mousedown" event to trigger the screen capture. This works perfectly the first time, however, when the user "clicks through" my application it deactivates it. In the Window_Deactivate event I am using the Window.Activate() method to try and re-activate my application, however it only manages to make the application's icon on the task bar flash, not reactivate the entire application/window.

Is there a way to "steal" the active window from a third party application every time my window is deactivated?

Note: The `Console.Writeline("Ater - Window is active?....")` returns false and the code never enters the exception.

XAML:

```
<Window Title=" Screen Capture" AllowsTransparency="True"
    WindowStyle="None" Background="{x:Null}" 
    Deactivated="Window_Deactivated" Activated="Window_Activated">
```

C#:

```
private void Window_Deactivated(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Window deactivated");
    Window window = (Window)sender;
    Console.WriteLine("Window Handle: {0}", windowHandle);
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Window {0}", window);
        window.Activate();
        window.Focus();
        Console.WriteLine("After - Window is active? {0}", window.IsActive);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {   
        Console.WriteLine("Window Activation FAILED");  
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to "steel" focus,

The reason trying to do this only blinks the tray icon is that in the past application used to steel focus all the time (because everyone thinks his/hers own app is more important then what the user is doing) - this was really annoying so MS blocked focus steeling

It seems to me like you are using the wrong technology, the solution for detecting action in other application is [hooks (MSDN link)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959(v=vs.85).aspx)

Specifically, the WH_MOUSE hook let you look at mouse events before the other application handles them and do whatever you want.

Note that installing an hook injects your DLL into the other process, so the hook code can't be written in .net (because there isn't a .net runtime in the other process just waiting to run random code) and it has to use some king of inter-process communication system to talk to your app so it can respond.